# curl : Depends: libcurl4 (= 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2) but 7.65.3-1ubuntu3 is to be installed

Tags: docker, curl

I keep getting unmet dependencies problem while installing docker and cant find a relevant solution to it. [Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5lmW.png)

Comment: Please, put your Dockerfile and `docker build`, `docker run` commands... It's not clear; very difficult to help you with so little information.

Comment: I havenot installed docker yet, I was trying to install docker but while installing docker from the documentation, i couldnt install curl and got the about errors.

Comment: curl : Depends: libcurl4 (= 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2) but 7.65.3-1ubuntu3 is to be installed

This error

Comment: Try with `sudo apt-get update –fix-missing`, `sudo dpkg –configure -a`, and `sudo apt-get install -f`